# How to throw an exception from ANTLR4 script?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I want my Antlr4 parser to throw `RecognitionException` when it doesn't understand the input **and** when the perfectly parsed input doesn't satisfy my custom requirements. In other words, I want to find an ability to throw `RecognitionException`, so that it goes through all error listeners, etc.

How should do this?

ps. I don't want to break the entire parsing cycle. I want it to continue, as it does after a parsing/syntax problem.

Answer (score 1):

Throw a [`ParseCancellationException`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/misc/ParseCancellationException.html). Keep in mind there are some semantics you'll want to preserve regarding the `ParserRuleContext.exception` field, as shown in [`BailErrorStrategy.java`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/BailErrorStrategy.java).

Edit: Sorry I misunderstood your question. The response to your revised question is you do not want to do that (report semantic errors while the parser is still going). If you want to report an error that was identified during semantic analysis (after the parse tree is fully created), you can call `Parser.notifyErrorListeners(Token, String, RecognitionException)`, or create your own customized error reporting mechanism.

Comment: when I throw `ParseCancellationException` it doesn't hit my error listener, but bubbles up, breaking the entire parsing. for that purpose I can easily use `IllegalStateException`